# Error when publishing SharePoint Workflow 2010 through SharePoint Designer 2013

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a simple SharePoint Workflow 2010 with one action -> Log message

But I always get the following error, this happen on the whole Office 365 SharePoint site, and it has the same issue when I change to another computer. The error is as below:

[image]

“Errors were found when compiling the workflow. The workflow files were saved but cannot be run”

The error detail was also not very informative:

“Unexpected error on server associating the workflow”

I have tried solutions below, but either of them works:

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/sharepointdevelopersupport/2014/09/10/sharepoint-designer-2013-unexpected-error-on-server-associating-the-workflow/

https://sharepoint-specialist.nu/sharepoint-designer-2013-error-unexpected-error-on-server-associating-the-workflow-235eaa801

https://www.sharepointsapiens.com/blog/sharepoint-designer-errors-found-compiling-workflow/

Can anybody help me with this issue?

Comment: This is an Office 365 bug leading to [Sharepoint-2010-Workflow-can-no-longer-be-published](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/SharePoint-Developer/Sharepoint-2010-Workflow-can-no-longer-be-published-on/td-p/364112)